# WOPI Host: Word file not edit on online server. but view working fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, ms-wopi

In my project, i have integrated Online Office server with WOPI.
but docx file not editing in online while view file online working fine.

In my local system all the functionality working fine. but on the server above error coming.

please help me out if you know about the these problem.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Sorry, this document cant be opened for editing

Comment: set the UserCanWrite to True and include HostEditUrl and EditModePostMessage properties under CheckFileInfo

Comment: I have already added this. nut still not working.

Comment: These edit working fine in my local system. but on the server, not working